# what is the difference between an assignment in one line vs multiple lines

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am practicing one question from [Swap Nodes in Pairs](https://leetcode.com/problems/swap-nodes-in-pairs/) . Based on the following code, does anyone know why the result is different if I put the assignment into separate lines vs one line?

```
class Solution:
    def swapPairs(self, head):
        prev, prev.next = self, head
        while prev.next and prev.next.next:
            a = prev.next
            b = a.next
            prev.next, b.next, a.next = b, a, b.next #what is difference if i seperate this line into following 3 statement?
            # prev.next = b
            # b.next = a
            # a.next = b.next
            prev = a
        return self.next
```

Answer (score 4):

The one-line version creates a temporary tuple in memory, so it's *kind of* doing:

```
tmp1 = b
tmp2 = a
tmp3 = b.next
prev.next = tmp1
b.next = tmp2
a.next = tmp3
```

When you split it up like you're doing in your second example, you end up reassigning `b.next` and then reading it AFTER that assignment, so its value has already changed...

```
prev.next = b
b.next = a.next # <-- overwrites b.next
a.next = b.next # <-- reads that new value back
```

This is why in general you **can't** swap two variables by doing:

```
a=b # <-- overwrites a
b=a # <-- reads that value back
```

but you **can** (at least in Python) do:

```
a,b = b,a
```

Answer (score 0):

You start out with the sequence

```
prev -> a -> b -> b.next
```

The first statement correctly swaps the middle pair to

```
prev -> b -> a -> b.next
```

That's because the entire right hand side is evaluated, and packed into a tuple *before* any assignments are made to the left hand side.

The sequential assignment ends up setting

```
prev -> b -> a -> a
```

This happens because the last assignment, `a.next = b.next` is evaluated only after the assignment `b.next = a`. At that point, `b.next` is `a`.

The correct assignment, using no temp variables, could be done in the following order:

```
prev.next = b
a.next = b.next
b.next = a
```